# Convert int to Glib::ustring w/o stringstream

Tags: c++, int, glib

I need to convert an integer to a Glib::ustring, but I don't want to use stringstream. Not that there's anything inherently WRONG with stringstream, but I don't want yet another library *just* to accomplish such a simple task.

My first instinct is to write a function with a big 'ol if-statement, or use an array of characters for each digit, but there has to be something cleaner. Is there any alternative?

Comment: `Glib::ustring str(std::to_string(123456));`

Comment: Okay, that's also an impressive solution, though it does still require an STL library, which some might not want. Surprised that no one online has actually mentioned that before. It's been a topic for years around the net, and everyone says to use stringstream >.<

Comment: I'm not familiar with `ustring` but won't the `format` function do this? `ustring text = ustring::format(123456);`

Comment: Yes, that apparently works as well. I feel slightly silly, but not very, as even the people on the Glib mailing list hadn't mentioned these!

Comment: As for not wanting to use the standard library, `ustring.h` has `#include <sstream>` and `#include <string>` right at the top so it's not like you can avoid it.

Comment: I'm surprised it segfaults, all `format` should be doing behind the scenes is using `std::wostringstream operator<<()` (or `ostringstream` if you're using narrow chars) with whatever you provide.

Comment: I had to update, it worked after all. Anyway, I'll leave my answer up for those that need it, especially with other alternative string classes. However, please do answer with your two solutions. The internet folks only recommend stringstream, which makes a number of us twitch involuntarily, not certain why (on either count).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Glib::ustring` provides a [`format`](https://developer.gnome.org/glibmm/stable/classGlib_1_1ustring.html#ab107f38a4f62c08156ca7235e4439792) static function that simply forwards whatever you throw at it (up to 8 arguments, no variadic template yet it seems) to a stringstream and returns the formatted string:

```
Glib::ustring text = Glib::ustring::format(123456);
```

Since c++11 the standard library also has an overloaded [`to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) method for converting integers and floats

```
Glib::ustring text(std::to_string(123456));
```

Comment: Once again, thanks for this. I dug through documentation for hours before wrapping my own. Glib is painfully impenetrable, at least to my eyes, and no one else seems to have mentioned this on the net. Oy.

Comment: @JasonMc92 Apparently it's been around since at least 2008 so it's definitely kind of strange that no one's mentioned it before.

Comment: Typical documentation paradox: "it's in the (impenetrable) docs, so we can assume that everyone knows." >.>

Comment: Good answer. I recommend `std::to_string()` because a glance at the respective pieces of code makes it quite obvious that it will be faster, due to having one job and doing it efficiently, versus the roundabout rigamarole of `Glib::ustring::format()`, which only makes sense for more complex tasks. The conversion from `std::string` to `Glib::ustring` is pretty much a no-op, since `Glib::ustring` works on the basis of a contained `std::string` and will just `std::move()` the result of `std::to_string()` into itself.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: This method is intended to avoid STL completely, for cases/libraries where that is necessary. However, Glib::ustring does indeed use STL anyway, just FYI. If you're using some other custom string class, or just feel like a smart aleck with Glib, this might still come in handy.

Yes, it is actually possible, though it does require a custom function. This works quite well thus far, and doesn't require any other libraries, besides the obvious Glib::ustring. You can substitute any other char-supporting string class, and just adjust the Glib::ustring lines accordingly.

```
Glib::ustring int_to_ustring(int num)
{
    bool neg = false;
    int sub = 0;
    char digit;
    //This is what we'll return.
    Glib::ustring str = "";

    //If number is 0, the math won't work. Just return the string "0".
    if(num == 0)
    {
        str = "0";
        return str;
    }
    //Else, if the number is negative...
    else if(num < 0)
    {
        //Store that information and make the number positive.
        neg = true;
        num = abs(num);
    }

    //Determine place value.
    int pv = 0;
    do
    {
        //Divide by a power of ten and trunicate decimal.
        sub = num / pow(10, pv);
        //Increase pv.
        pv++;
    }
    //If we got zero, then we're too large.
    while(sub != 0);

    //NOTE: The above seems to make the place value two-too-large?

    //Loop backwards through the place values.
    for(pv; pv >= 0; pv--)
    {
        sub = num / pow(10, pv);
        num -= sub*(pow(10, pv));

        if(sub < 0 || sub > 10)
        {
            //Throw an error. I'm just using this as a placeholder.
            std::cout << "Something went really weird." << std::endl;
        }

        //The char code for the digit is always 48 more than the digit.
        digit = sub + 48;
        //If this isn't a leading zero...
        if(!(str == "" && digit == '0'))
        {
            //This is the best way to push a char to a ustring.
            str.insert(str.end(), digit);
        }
    }

    //If that number was negative, insert the negative sign.
    if(neg)
        str.insert(str.begin(), '-');

    return str;
}
```

(By the by, suggested improvements are welcomed! I'm hoping to make this more efficient yet.)

Comment: I'll update my post when I find time, but Christian Gollwitzer on USENET pointed out a much more efficient way of parsing out the digits. One only needs to reverse them.
`if (i<0) { print "-"; i=-i }

i=12345678
while i {
  print i % 10
  i = i/10
} `